# What's the reason for footnote 37 in 3.7.4.2[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]/2 in C++14?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, c++14

§3.7.4.2/2 contains the following sentences:

> The global `operator delete` with exactly two parameters, the second of
>   which has type `std::size_t`, is a usual deallocation function.
>   Similarly, the global `operator delete[]` with exactly one parameter is
>   a usual deallocation function. The global operator `delete[]` with
>   exactly two parameters, the second of which has type `std::size_t`, is a
>   usual deallocation function.<sup>37</sup>

37) This deallocation function precludes use of an allocation function `void operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t)` as a
placement allocation function.

Not only did I not understand the reason for this footnote, but also I noticed that this placement form, alluded in the footnote, doesn't exist in **§18.6.1.3 Placement Forms [new.delete.placement]**.

**Edit** In order to verify what [@Sander De Dicker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822669/sander-de-dycker) is saying in his answer, I tested the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

void* operator new  (std::size_t count, int i1, int i2, int i3){
    void *p = malloc(count);
    if (!p) throw std::bad_alloc{};
    std::cout << "operator new" << '\n';
    return p;
}

void operator delete (void* p, int j1, int j2, int j3)
{
    free(p);
    std::cout << "operator delete" << '\n';
}

class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; };
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        A *p = new(0, 0, 0) A;
        delete p;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc&) { exit(1); }
}
```

In all 3 compilers that I have available (VS2015, clang and g++) the code invoked the placement `operator new(size_t, int, int, int)`, but didn't invoke the placement `operator delete(void*, int, int, int)`, but the `operator delete(void*)`. Now, I'm more confused than I was when I posted the question.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c8fb1872168d868)

Comment: I think it means that one (a user) cannot define an `operator new(size_t, size_t)` because this requires a corresponding `operator delete(size_t, size_t)` for deletions that occur due to exceptions being thrown during the construction within the allocation via this placement-new function.

Comment: @dyp But according to §18.6.1.3, the language does not allow this placement form for `operator new`.

Comment: I don't quite see how [new.delete.placement] forbids this allocation function. Could you please elaborate? Note: I've used the term "requires" in my previous comment, but that is too strong: A corresponding deallocation function is not *required*, but w/o a corresponding deallocation function, you'd get a leak in that scenario. (I'm not sure if the library version would get called.)

Comment: @dyp As far as I can understand, §18.6.1.3 specifies which placement forms are allowed by the language.

Comment: Placement delete is an odd beast; it is only called when the constructor called by the placement new throws.

Comment: @T.C. I can confirm this by throwing inside the constructor `A()`. In this case the `operator delete(void*, int, int, int)` is called. But according to §5.3.4/22 it should also be called in the example above. Why it doesn't?

Comment: That paragraph only deals with handling deallocation when the construction throws. `delete x;` is specified separately (in 5.3.5 [expr.delete]) and only uses the normal deallocation functions. Practical reason: the compiler only knows what arguments to pass to the placement delete while you are in the placement new.

Comment: @T.C. `Practical reason: the compiler only knows what arguments to pass to the placement delete while you are in the placement new.` **Brilliant**.

Comment: @T.C. This is strange: when `A()` throws, but the exception is not caught in `main()`, neither `~A()` nor `operator delete(void*, int, int, int)` are invoked. I tried to find an explanation, to no avail.

Comment: `~A()` will never be called since a `A` is never successfully constructed. The deallocation is part of stack unwinding, and when no matching handler is found it's up to the implementation whether the stack is unwound.

Comment: @T.C. I shouldn't have complained about `~A()`. This was just a distraction of mine. But in order for `operator delete(void*, int, int, int)` to be invoked, the exception thrown by `A()` should be caught by a try-block surrounding the constructor call. Wouldn't that start stack unwinding?

Comment: @Belloc You presuppose an implicit try-catch(...)-deallocate-rethrow around `new`. I need to check how the standard specifies it, but the implementations essentially treat the deallocation-on-throw as another destructor to run when stack unwinding takes place. That is, it's just as if you call `operator new`, stashed the result in a scope guard that calls the deallocation function on destruction, call the constructor, and then dismiss the scope guard. I can actually write this manually and get clang/gcc to produce identical assembly.

Comment: @T.C. [This](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/l9ZOsATprVI/RphHIZUGCgAJ) (ongoing) discussion helped me to understand what you said above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*C.3.2 [diff.cpp11.basic]* explains that :

> **C.3.2 Clause 3 : basic concepts [diff.cpp11.basic]**
>
> 3.7.4.2
>
> **Change**: New usual (non-placement) deallocator
>
> **Rationale**: Required for sized deallocation.
>
> **Effect on original feature**: Valid C++ 2011 code could declare a global placement allocation function and deallocation function as follows:
>
> `void operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t);`
>
> `void operator delete(void*, std::size_t) noexcept;`
>
> In this International Standard, however, the declaration of `operator delete`
> might match a predefined usual (non-placement) `operator delete` (3.7.4). If so, the program is ill-formed, as it was for class member allocation functions and deallocation functions (5.3.4).

In other words, this is a breaking change with the previous standard (C++11). In C++11, it was allowed to define such `operator delete`, whereas in C++14 the program would be ill formed.

### **Edit - some further clarification based on comments** :

- *18.6.1.3 [new.delete.placement]* lists the reserved placement forms. You are however allowed to declare other (non-reserved) ones in your code. So, that part of the standard doesn't apply to your question.
- *3.7.4.2 [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]* has the above mentioned change compared to C++11, which disallows the placement forms `operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t)` and `operator delete(void*, std::size_t)`, because the latter might match a predefined non-placement `operator delete`. This change is further documented in *C.3.2 [diff.cpp11.basic]*.
- Your edited question has already been addressed in comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998748/whats-the-reason-for-footnote-37-in-3-7-4-2basic-stc-dynamic-deallocation-2-i/33999138#comment55765926_33998748), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998748/whats-the-reason-for-footnote-37-in-3-7-4-2basic-stc-dynamic-deallocation-2-i/33999138#comment55766690_33998748)) by [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) , but I'll include it here for completeness :
  The reason your custom `operator delete(void*, int, int, int)` is not called, is because the `operator new(std::size_t, int, int, int)` didn't throw an exception. *5.3.4 [expr.new]* explains that in *§20-23*.

Comment: See also: [expr.new]p22 (in a recent draft; not sure if it's already in C++14)

Comment: C++11 also doesn't mention the placement forms you cited above in §18.6.1.3. As far as I can understand, §18.6.1.3 specifies which placement forms are allowed by the language.

Comment: @Belloc : 18.6.1.3 lists the reserved placement forms. That doesn't mean you cannot declare others (ie. non-reserved ones) in your code. The footnote you're asking about though, says that additionally, you also are not allowed to declare a `void operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t)` placement allocation function (this was allowed in C++11, but no longer in C++14).

Comment: For me the word `reserved` means what is just written in §18.6.1.3/1,  that is: `a C++ program may not define functions that displace the versions in the Standard C++ library`. In other words, the placement forms are not replaceable.

Comment: @Belloc : for displacement, the function signature has to match the version being displaced. Since `void operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t)` is not reserved according to 18.6.1.3, that paragraph doesn't apply. The footnote you mentioned *does* though.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But where in the Standard can I find any reference to the fact that a user is free to define these so called "non-reserved" placement forms?

Comment: @Belloc : I don't know if the standard explicitly states that this is allowed, but it doesn't disallow it. In fact, if you read through **5.3.4 [expr.new]** for example, you'll find description and examples of how to do just that. Furthermore, **C.3.2** (see my answer) specifically mentions it was allowed in C++11.

Comment: See the **Edit** section in my question above.